# tooltip in lightbox not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, lightbox

I am using [lightbox](http://particletree.com/examples/lightbox/) and [wz_tooltip](http://www.koders.com/javascript/fidA921B6A6513EDD70F56977F2515191E5333BF2E5.aspx?s=%22Christophe+Porteneuve%22) they both working individually fine. 
means when i use tootip for some lightbox link on the page it shows me properly and when i click on that link i can see lightbox properly but when i use tootip function for the link in the lightbox it doesn't work properly. it hides behind the lightbox. i think the problem may occur due to the z-index but i don't find any solution yet.

I want some example where custom tootip is used in lightbox link please i dont want to use jquery and title parameter of the link.

Regards,

Salil

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like Firebug or Web Inspector to see what containing element the tooltip has (i.e. the highest parent).

Set its `z-index` to higher than the modal.

You may need to use `!important`.

Comment: thanx alex for quick reply, but z-index is applied by using js in wz_tooltip. i hard code it to 9999 and for lightbox 9000 but still it didn't work. Can u please provide me demo where Custom tooltip is used in alightbox other than jquery

Answer (score 0):

HI Salil,

Agian Stuck in Tooltip Try Position If your position is absolute then and then Z-index work otherwise not ok, Try Position Relative and by Setting Margin too,

Ok

Bye Mayur Mate